# Java AWT Graphics Class: Making Rows and Columns of Squares

Tags: java, graphics, 2d, graphics2d

I'm using the java.awt graphics class, and I'm trying to make rows and squares.
I can't seem to get the layout of the rows correctly.

I'm trying to code 8 rows with 3 columns each. However, I just get 2 rows with 12 columns.

If somebody can help me to create the outcome that I want, that would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
int x = 70;
int y = 80;
int w = 30;
int h = 35;
for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++) { 
    for(int col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
        g.fillRect( x, y, w, h );
        g.fillRect( x, y + h + 20, w, h );
        x += w + 15;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Here's the output: [2 rows, 12 columns of squares](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOsQ2.png)

Comment: Why do you have two `fillRect(...)` statements in the loop? Why are you using 3 and 4 as the indexes for your loops? What happens if your requirement is to paint 7 columns? How could you ever do this if you paint two rectangles each time? Your question is about 8 rows and 3 columns. So keep the looping code simple. Your indexes should be 8 and 3 and each iteration will draw a single rectangle for a total of 24 rectangles.

Answer (score 1):

Beware of how you are updating your position information.  For example, you should only be updating the `x` position in the inner loop and resetting to `0` before entering the inner loop, and the `y` position should only be updated on each new row.

Alternatively, you could calculate the position directly, based on the row/column index and the row/column height, as demonstrated below.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private static int COLUMN_COUNT = 3;
        private static int ROW_COUNT = 8;

        private static int COLUMN_WIDTH = 30;
        private static int ROW_HEIGHT = 35;

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(3 * COLUMN_WIDTH, 8 * ROW_HEIGHT);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            int columnWidth = getWidth() / 3;
            int rowHeight = getHeight() / 8;

            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;

            for (int row = 0; row < ROW_COUNT; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < COLUMN_COUNT ; col++) {
                    if (col % 2 == 0) {
                        x = columnWidth * col;
                        y = rowHeight * row;
                        g2d.fillRect(x + 2, y + 2, columnWidth - 4, rowHeight - 4);
                    }
                }
            }

            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```